# Detecting attributes of elements in the HTML DOM with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

So much confusion, so few answers. I'm trying to loop through the DOM, looking for a specific node by id, however, this code has several problems for which I have no explanation. First, the length of the childNodes list comes up as '5'. Two "ul"'s, two "id"'s, if those count...and one for luck?

Second, it dies at `if(y[i].hasAttribute('id')===true)`. Firebug says this is not a function. I have no reason to not believe it, but am not sure why it isn't.

Thank you for any help.

```
<div id="list">
<ul id="first"></ul>
<ul  id="second"></ul>
</div>
    <script>
        var comments=document.getElementById('list')
                        var y=comments.childNodes;
                        var count=y.length
                        for(i=0;i<count;i++)
                        {
                            document.write(y.length);
                            if(y[i].hasAttribute('id')===true)
                            { document.write('here!');}

                        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Maybe try: `if (y[i].nodeType === 1 && y[i].hasAttribute('id') === true) {` so that you only check `Element` nodes. **Or**, use `var y = comments.children;` to only loop over `Element` nodex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `childNodes` attribute contains *all* nodes in the DOM, which specifically means, it includes text nodes. you have 3 of them - the newline/linefeed characters inside your div.

you can test for element children using the `nodeType` attribute ( see eg. [here](http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/dom-nodetype-constants/); `1`represents `ELEMENT_NODE`, `3` stands for `TEXT_NODE`).

Comment: Ahh, I see, so this is somewhat similar to having to check xml so you don't read white space? Thank you very much for the link! I would have never solved this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a tool like Firebug and inspect the DOM itself, you would see all the children of an element and the difference between .children and .childNodes .

It's by hunting around in the DOM that I discovered why there are so many things that at first appear to be duplicates of each other, but are definitely not. The Mozilla developers site developer.mozilla.org is also a wealth of information.